# Remove icon from window

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, qicon, qwindow

I've discovered that if I remove all flags from a `QDialog`, and set Windows flags to `QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint` and `QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint`, the icon disappears, but also the close button. Unfortunately, if I add the flag of `QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint`, the icon returns.

Is there a way that I can add a close button to the window without having the icon?

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(1, 1)
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        self.title_bar = "Graph Filter"
        self.graph_icon = QtGui.QIcon("views/resources/icons/hexagon.png")
        self.empty_icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)

        self.width = 600
        self.height = 600

        rectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        center_point = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        rectangle.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.move(rectangle.topLeft())


        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(self.empty_icon)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title_bar)
        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
```

here there's no icon, but no close button:
[image: here there's no icon, but no close button]

here there is an icon space, but no close button:
[image: here there is an icon space, but no close button]

The ideal world is to have no icon and a close button.

> As you can see in the images, a transparent icon is not good either, because the space remains there.

Answer (score 1):

Try it `windowflags.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2013 Riverbank Computing Limited.
## Copyright (C) 2010 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies).
## All rights reserved.
##
## This file is part of the examples of PyQt.
##
## $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:BSD$
## You may use this file under the terms of the BSD license as follows:
##
## "Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
## modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
## met:
##   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
##   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
##     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
##     the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
##     distribution.
##   * Neither the name of Nokia Corporation and its Subsidiary(-ies) nor
##     the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote
##     products derived from this software without specific prior written
##     permission.
##
## THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
## "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
## A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
## OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
## SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
## LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
## DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
## THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
## (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
## OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE."
## $QT_END_LICENSE$
##
#############################################################################


from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QGridLayout, QGroupBox,
        QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout,
        QWidget)


class PreviewWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PreviewWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)

        closeButton = QPushButton("&Close")
        closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(closeButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Preview")

    def setWindowFlags(self, flags):
        super(PreviewWindow, self).setWindowFlags(flags)

        flag_type = (flags & Qt.WindowType_Mask)

        if flag_type == Qt.Window:
            text = "Qt.Window"
        elif flag_type == Qt.Dialog:
            text = "Qt.Dialog"
        elif flag_type == Qt.Sheet:
            text = "Qt.Sheet"
        elif flag_type == Qt.Drawer:
            text = "Qt.Drawer"
        elif flag_type == Qt.Popup:
            text = "Qt.Popup"
        elif flag_type == Qt.Tool:
            text = "Qt.Tool"
        elif flag_type == Qt.ToolTip:
            text = "Qt.ToolTip"
        elif flag_type == Qt.SplashScreen:
            text = "Qt.SplashScreen"
        else:
            text = ""

        if flags & Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint"
        if flags & Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint"
        if flags & Qt.FramelessWindowHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.FramelessWindowHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowTitleHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowTitleHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowShadeButtonHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowShadeButtonHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint"
        if flags & Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint"
        if flags & Qt.CustomizeWindowHint:
            text += "\n| Qt.CustomizeWindowHint"

        self.textEdit.setPlainText(text)


class ControllerWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ControllerWindow, self).__init__()

        self.previewWindow = PreviewWindow(self)

        self.createTypeGroupBox()
        self.createHintsGroupBox()

        quitButton = QPushButton("&Quit")
        quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

        bottomLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        bottomLayout.addStretch()
        bottomLayout.addWidget(quitButton)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.typeGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.hintsGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addLayout(bottomLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Window Flags")
        self.updatePreview()

    def updatePreview(self):
        flags = Qt.WindowFlags()

        if self.windowRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.Window
        elif self.dialogRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.Dialog
        elif self.sheetRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.Sheet
        elif self.drawerRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.Drawer
        elif self.popupRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.Popup
        elif self.toolRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.Tool
        elif self.toolTipRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.ToolTip
        elif self.splashScreenRadioButton.isChecked():
            flags = Qt.SplashScreen

        if self.msWindowsFixedSizeDialogCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint            
        if self.x11BypassWindowManagerCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint
        if self.framelessWindowCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.FramelessWindowHint
        if self.windowTitleCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowTitleHint
        if self.windowSystemMenuCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint
        if self.windowMinimizeButtonCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
        if self.windowMaximizeButtonCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint
        if self.windowCloseButtonCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
        if self.windowContextHelpButtonCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint
        if self.windowShadeButtonCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowShadeButtonHint
        if self.windowStaysOnTopCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        if self.windowStaysOnBottomCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint
        if self.customizeWindowHintCheckBox.isChecked():
            flags |= Qt.CustomizeWindowHint

        self.previewWindow.setWindowFlags(flags)

        pos = self.previewWindow.pos()

        if pos.x() < 0:
            pos.setX(0)

        if pos.y() < 0:
            pos.setY(0)

        self.previewWindow.move(pos)
        self.previewWindow.show()

    def createTypeGroupBox(self):
        self.typeGroupBox = QGroupBox("Type")

        self.windowRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Window")
        self.dialogRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Dialog")
        self.sheetRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Sheet")
        self.drawerRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Drawer")
        self.popupRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Popup")
        self.toolRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Tool")
        self.toolTipRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Tooltip")
        self.splashScreenRadioButton = self.createRadioButton("Splash screen")
        self.windowRadioButton.setChecked(True)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.windowRadioButton, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.dialogRadioButton, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.sheetRadioButton, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.drawerRadioButton, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.popupRadioButton, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolRadioButton, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolTipRadioButton, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.splashScreenRadioButton, 3, 1)
        self.typeGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createHintsGroupBox(self):
        self.hintsGroupBox = QGroupBox("Hints")

        self.msWindowsFixedSizeDialogCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("MS Windows fixed size dialog")
        self.x11BypassWindowManagerCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("X11 bypass window manager")
        self.framelessWindowCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Frameless window")
        self.windowTitleCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window title")
        self.windowSystemMenuCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window system menu")
        self.windowMinimizeButtonCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window minimize button")
        self.windowMaximizeButtonCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window maximize button")
        self.windowCloseButtonCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window close button")
        self.windowContextHelpButtonCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window context help button")
        self.windowShadeButtonCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window shade button")
        self.windowStaysOnTopCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window stays on top")
        self.windowStaysOnBottomCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Window stays on bottom")
        self.customizeWindowHintCheckBox = self.createCheckBox("Customize window")

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.msWindowsFixedSizeDialogCheckBox, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.x11BypassWindowManagerCheckBox, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.framelessWindowCheckBox, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowTitleCheckBox, 3, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowSystemMenuCheckBox, 4, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowMinimizeButtonCheckBox, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowMaximizeButtonCheckBox, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowCloseButtonCheckBox, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowContextHelpButtonCheckBox, 3, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowShadeButtonCheckBox, 4, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowStaysOnTopCheckBox, 5, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.windowStaysOnBottomCheckBox, 6, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.customizeWindowHintCheckBox, 5, 0)
        self.hintsGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def createCheckBox(self, text):
        checkBox = QCheckBox(text)
        checkBox.clicked.connect(self.updatePreview)
        return checkBox

    def createRadioButton(self, text):
        button = QRadioButton(text)
        button.clicked.connect(self.updatePreview)
        return button


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    controller = ControllerWindow()
    controller.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I loved the solution! It's really good to see the appearance changing depending on the flags on demand. The Drawer and Tool options kinda works, but there's a problem. I'm using the main window of my program as a Tool, and when I click on the close button it doesn't stop executing. Also, is there a way to change the appearance of this tiny close button to look more like the normal ones?